# How to extend the _alsoResize function of the resizable plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

How to extend the _alsoResize function of the resizable plugin?

Comment: you have to put the reference code to view the plugin

Comment: It depends...what do you want to extend it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to to extend the whole `resize` portion of of the widget plugin, for example:

```
$.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "alsoResize", {
    resize: function (event, ui) {
       //your own resize implementation...
    }
});
```

The `start` and `stop` from [the original `alsoResize` plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.6/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js#L529) will stay there.  [Here's an example using the extension method above](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZmmLY/).